# access a secure api

Tags: eclipse, security, api, blackberry

Can anyone tell me why this happen when i install the real device on my 
blackberry.
I am using blackberry web/widget to develop app BB and the language that i used 
is
phonegap which is support .html, .css, .javascript.

The app can be installed but after install the app does not have icon.

Then when click on run the error msg is,
“Error starting Carl’s Jr. Module CarlsJr attempt to access a secure api”

Any answer will be highly appreciated!

thanks,

regards,
Jamaley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds very much like you haven't signed your code.

RIM track the use of some sensitive BlackBerry APIs. This is indicated in the API reference documentation by a lock icon or are otherwise noted as "signed".

Please see the following url for more information about these keys and how to request yours

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp

Cheers

Ray

Comment: You're welcome, it usually takes a couple of days for your keys to arrive. The last time I ordered some it cost $20

Comment: thanks dude for your response. i have a few question again. why i have signed the code because i am not used cryptography API, i am using phonegap API? and if i signed the code, is it possible to run the application in real device and can i run many application with one signed code or each application need one signed code.. thanks     regards, jamaley.

Comment: PhoneGap is subject to the same rules as all other applications, this is because you are using the same java api's. The only difference is you are calling them through javascript. It's an abstraction and not a replacement. Also because it needs to work with a large variety of applications it contains many more API's that you necessarily need in your application. There is a utility that comes with the SDK that makes signing all your cod files simple to do. using eclipse you can access it from project --> blackberry --> sign with signature tool

Comment: You will need to sign your app every time you compile it and want to run it on a phone. The number of signatures will depend on the cod files. The sensitive api list is not only cryptography. For a complete list of RIM controlled APIs, refer to the API reference included with the BlackBerry® Java® Development Environment (BlackBerry JDE) download.

Comment: "You will need to sign your app every time you compile it and want to run it on a phone"..so that you mean, I need to pay $20 for each application? thanks for your comment..

Comment: No you can use the same key for many applications. You pay $20 once.

Comment: I see..than if i upload the application in app world then the user download it, is it my app can run on their real device or the user need to pay $20 for sign ID? thanks dude..

Comment: no one downloading apps from appworld needs to pay $20 to buy or use these keys, it's only for the developer

Comment: is that the correct link to buy sign ID http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Applications-and-code-signing-Start-to-Finish/ta-p/445848 and these fill form link https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/ thanks dude..i am sorry to take your time to help me..

Comment: yes, BlackBerry Code Signing Keys Order Form looks correct to me

Comment: thanks dude.. After I go to above link and fill in the form to buy, I got error.. can I get your email, I want to pm you the screenshot..

Comment: I'm not going to be able to help you with that as I don't work for RIM, I think you need to contact RIM's customer support :)

Comment: yes you are write dude..i am sorry and thank you very much for your respond. your answer are valuable to me..cheers..^__^